# Local DynamoDB Tables Backup

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I want to back my DynamoDB local server. I have install  DynamoDB  server in Linux machine. Some sites are refer to create a BASH file in Linux os and connect to S3 bucket, but in local machine we don't have S3 bucket.
   So i am stuck with my work, Please help me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the database file created by DynamoDb local. From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html):

> -dbPath value — The directory where DynamoDB will write its database file. If you do not specify this option, the file will be written to
>   the current directory. Note that you cannot specify both -dbPath and
>   -inMemory at once.

The file name would be of the form `youraccesskeyid_region.db`. If you used the `-sharedDb` option, the file name would be `shared-local-instance.db`

By default, the file is created in the directory from which you ran dynamodb local. To restore you'll have to the copy the same file and while running dynamodb, specify the same `dbPath`.